# sql default value on join

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, automationstudio

I have a sql query taking everything from one table (sdrcraw) and populating it in a 2nd table. The 2nd table has an additional column called 'local' and this gets populated with a join on country from the localelookup table.

This works as it should. I would like to add a default value in the event that a country is missing from the locallookup table. If the join returns a null then set that null local to 'AA' as an example.

```
sdrcraw.BIGuid, 
sdrcraw.SubsciberKey, 
sdrcraw.FIrstName, 
sdrcraw.Accountnumber, 
sdrcraw.Country, 
sdrcraw.MobileNo, 
localelookup.locale
FROM sdrcraw
LEFT JOIN [localelookup]
ON sdrcraw.country = localelookup.country
```

Comment: also got it work this way.

COALESCE(localelookup.locale,'AA') AS locale

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a case statement as following:

```
SELECT
    sdrcraw.BIGuid,
    sdrcraw.SubsciberKey,
    sdrcraw.FIrstName,
    sdrcraw.Accountnumber,
    sdrcraw.Country,
    sdrcraw.MobileNo,
    CASE
        WHEN localelookup.locale IS NULL THEN 'AA'
        ELSE localelookup.locale
    END AS locale
FROM
    sdrcraw
    LEFT JOIN [localelookup] ON sdrcraw.country = localelookup.country
```

Comment: thanks, I did try a version of case but got an error.

copied and pasted and getting this error message. doesn't like the IS NULL.

'An error occurred while checking the query syntax. Errors: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IS'. '

Answer (score 2):

@Lyslexic - Should not the CASE logic be like this (see below)--basically, you are missing WHEN after CASE keyword:

CASE
WHEN localelookup.locale IS NULL THEN 'AA'
ELSE localelookup.locale
END AS locale

Comment: Right, I should’ve tested my query before posting. Thanks for pointing that out, I’ve updated my answer.